# How to Loop Through List and Print Each Item But Include Previous with Each Line

Tags: python, list

So I have this code right now but the problem is it will loop through the entire list and print is as one.

Here is the data I am reading.

`[('Bob', '1\n2\n3'), ('Joe', '4\n5\n6')]`

```py
formatted_conversations = []
for conv in conversations:
    speaker, message = conv
    if len(formatted_conversations) == 0 or formatted_conversations[-1].split(" : ")[0] != speaker:
        formatted_conversations.append(speaker + " : " + message)
    else:
        formatted_conversations[-1] += "\n" + message
conversations=[]
for c in formatted_conversations:
    conversations.append(c.split(" : "))
```

So right now what happens is it automatically prints `Bob 1,2,3` as one.

But I need it to print like this

```
Bob: 1
Bob: 1
2
Bob: 1
2
3
Joe:4
Joe:4
5
Joe: 4
5
6
```

So essentially it prints as 3 vs 1 and it adds the previous list each time and switches when it sees the new person with the :

Comment: Change `\n` to space when concatenating to the previous item?

Comment: that prints as Bob 1 2 3 all on one line. I need them to be separate but include the previous message

Comment: If you print each list element on its own line you'll get that.

Comment: what I am trying to get is it to print Bob 1 first, then Bob 1 and 2, then Bob 1, 2 and 3 but all on a new line

Answer (score 0):

To include the old one append the last row

```
formatted_conversations.append(formatted_conversations[-1])
```

The new code:

```
formatted_conversations = []
for conv in conversations:
    speaker, message = conv
    if len(formatted_conversations) == 0 or formatted_conversations[-1].split(" : ")[0] != speaker:
        formatted_conversations.append(speaker + " : " + message)
    else:
        formatted_conversations.append(formatted_conversations[-1])
        formatted_conversations[-1] += "\n" + message
conversations=[]
for c in formatted_conversations:
    c = c.split(" : ")
    print(c[0] , ":" , c[1])
    conversations.append(c[0] + ":" + c[1])
```

output:

```
Bob : 1
Bob : 1
2
Bob : 1
2
3
Joe : 4
Joe : 4
5
Joe : 4
5
6
```

Comment: that just prints it all on the same line as one. So it just says bob 1 2 3

Comment: now it prints each one on a line and prints the message on separate lines

Comment: what did you even change in my code? it looks the exact same

Comment: The last for loop is changed to print the data (and save it in conversations in the right way, also this line was added formatted_conversations.append(formatted_conversations[-1])

Answer (score 0):

I dont know your data format, I would do it something like this:

```
data = [('Bob', '1\n2\n3'), ('Joe', '1\n2\n3')]


def print_repeated(prefix, data):
    data = data.split("\n")
    last_print = f"{prefix}: {data[0]}"
    print(last_print)
    for item in data[1:]:
        last_print += "\n" + str(item)
        print(last_print)


print_repeated(data[0][0], data[0][1])


for name, values in data:
    print_repeated(name, values)
```

This outputs:

```
Bob: 1
Bob: 1
2
Bob: 1
2
3
Joe: 4
Joe: 4
5
Joe: 4
5
6
```

Comment: so it's reading off a script written in google docs. For Bob 1 2 , the number 2 must be on a new line, so not side by side like in your output.

Comment: @jeeeez I modified it to follow your expected output

Comment: @jheeez Are you trying to print the string, or join the string into one?

Comment: it's reading a google word doc off a script and taking a screenshot per line. So it sc Bob 1, then Bob 1 \n/ 2, then checks for the next character Joe: 1 , Joe 1 and 2 etc. but my current code straight up takes the screenshot of Bob: 1 2 3 in one without taking sc of Bob 1 first, then bob 1 2

Comment: here's my updated data that it's reading `[('Bob', '1\n2\n3'), ('Joe', '1\n2\n3')]
`

Comment: @jeeeez And you want to print that data to the console in the format described in the question?

Comment: the data I just commented needs to print just like you show in your output in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

After concatenating the message to the string, append `formatted_conversations[-1]` to the result list so you get all the incremental conversations.

```
conversations = [('Bob', '1\n2\n3'), ('Joe', '4\n5\n6')] 
formatted_conversations = []
for speaker, messages in conversations:
    output = speaker + ': ' + messages[0]
    formatted_conversations.append(output)
    for message in messages.split('\n')[1:]:
        output += '\n' + message
        formatted_conversations.append(output)

print(*formatted_conversations, sep="\n")
```

Output is:

```
Bob : 1
Bob : 1
2
Bob : 1
2
3
Joe : 4
Joe : 4
5
Joe : 4
5
6
```

Comment: I updated my post to show the layout I need. Tom's answer output example is showing how I need the result to be.

Comment: OK, then go back to use `\n` as the separator. The algorithm is the same.

Comment: the data should be [bob 1] [bob 1, 2] [bob 1, 2 3] like that

Comment: I ran my script and it produces the exact output you show in the question.

Comment: Please edit the question and show the input and desired output with proper formatting. Use a code block to format it.

Comment: the data looks like this `[('Bob', '1\n2\n3'), ('Joe', '1\n2\n3')]
`

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect that input.